# PostgreSQL Array Contains vs JOIN (performance)

Tags: postgresql

I have a model in which a person can receive a gift for attending one event or receive multiple gifts for attending multiple events. The gift to person or multiple gifts to person is considered one transaction in both cases. I'm using PostgreSQL to implement this model.

For example,

- if you attend to certain event, you will receive a gift (a single transaction of gift to person).
- And another example, you attend to a set of events therefore you receive a set of gifts for these events (in a single transaction of gifts to person).

So, in the majority of cases, only one gift to one person will be transacted. But there will be a few cases of the second example.

In order to handle this cases, i have two options,

1. the first one is use a postgres array and query by array contains,
2. and the second one is create a new table of transaction_events and make a join to query by event.

I wanted to know which option is more performant and which option the community recommends. Tanking into account that the most transaction will contains only one event and also that i cannot change the transactions model.

Answer (score 0):

The second option will perform better, and it has the added benefit that you can have foreign key constraints to enforce data integrity.

In most cases, it is a good idea to avoid composite types like arrays or JSON in the database.